# How to remove an item from an array in a React component after an axios delete request has completed?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I've built a React component that displays a list of items returned from MongoDB inside an array. The individual items can be modified or deleted. To delete an item, the user clicks on a button which opens a modal window inside a child component. Once an item is deleted by a user, the item should be removed from the "matches" array and the parent component should be re-rendered automatically with the updated array displayed.

I built a function called handleUpdate(), which is supposed to filter out the deleted item from the array after the axios delete request has completed. This is where I am having issues, as although the actual axios delete request works as expected, only when the component is manually refreshed, does the array show the updated list of items.

Can somebody explain how I can get the component to automatically refresh/update after the delete request, with the deleted data removed from the array? Thank you in advance for any help.

Main component code:

```
export default function UpcomingFixtures() {

const [matches, setMatches] = useState([]);
const [pageNumber, setPageNumber] = useState(1)
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true)
const url = "http://localhost:5000/match";

useEffect(() => {
  upcomingMatches(page number);
}, [pageNumber])

const upcomingMatches = async (pageNumber) => {
  try {
     await axios
     .get(`${url}/paginate/${team}?page=${pageNumber}&limit=5`)
     .then( res => {
        setMatches(p => [...p, ...res.data.results]);
        setLoading(false)
    });
  } catch(err) {
     console.error(err);
 }
}

const handleUpdate = () => {
  const newMatches = matches.filter(match => match.id !== id)
setMatches(newMatches);
}

return (
   (matches.map(match => {
       const { myTeam, opposition, homeAway, createdAt, _id } = match 
       return (
          <Card variant="outlined" key={match._id}>
              <CardContent>...</CardContent>
                 <Button type="submit">
                    <DeleteMatchDialog 
                       myTeam={myTeam} 
                       opposition={opposition} 
                       id={_id} 
                       handleUpdate={handleUpdate}/>
                  </Button>
            </Card>
      )});
```

Delete Modal code:

```
export default function DeleteMatchDialog(props) {

//props
const { id, handleUpdate, opposition } = props;

const deleteMatch = async (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  try {
  await axios.delete(`${url}/delete/${id}`)
  .then(res => {
    handleUpdate(id);
  })
  } catch (err) {
  console.log(err)
 }
}

return (
<Button onClick={handleDelete} Delete </Button>
 <Dialog>
   <form onSubmit={deleteMatch}>
        <Button type="submit">
           Delete 
        </Button>
    </form>
  </Dialog>
 );
}
```

EDIT - Updated question 15/05/21

Comment: Your code seems fine. What is value of you get from upcomingmatches api after you delete the last item?

Comment: `When the final remaining item in the array is deleted` - so what's the response from the server from /upcomingmatches after you delete the last item?

Comment: I've checked the console in the web browser. Any time the final item is deleted i get a "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request)" message.

Comment: @cmc1993 so that means it isn't going to execute the success callback that is supposed to set it to an empty array...

Comment: Voting to close as this is not React issue, but server side issue.

Comment: @TJ ok thanks, I will look into my server-side code to see if a solution lies there.